# Check for length of a character string in SAS Proc Format

Tags: validation, sas, format, proc

I would like to write a PROC FORMAT to check for errors in a variable that serves as a unique identifier. The variable is a character string of length 16, and it usually has a number of trailing zeros, like so:

```
0000001234567890
```

I would like the PROC to output an error to the log if, for example, the variable is null or if the length of the sting is different from 16. Can this be done in the same proc, without having to go through functions such as length()?

what I would like to obtain is something like:

```
proc format;
value $ id_error
     ' ' = _ERROR_
     *length ne 16 = _ERROR_;
     *other errors* = _ERROR_;
     other = 'OK';
run;
```

Is something equivalent to the above possible to do with a single proc format?

Comment: Umm... could you do it the other way around -eg: `'0000000000000000' - '9999999999999999' = 'OK'; other = _ERROR_;` ? Anyway - is there any harm in doing this in a datastep to decide the validity of the field?

Comment: Wait, can I specify ranges in character strings too? If so, great.

Comment: You can use character ranges but they sort alphabetically. Look into PROC FCMP and a function instead.

Comment: @JonClements Unfortunately that wouldn't help in this case; for example, '9' is between '0000000' and '9999999'.

Answer (score 0):

Reeza's suggestion to use `PROC FCMP` is along the right path I think.  You can't really check for length in a format without it.

This is covered in the documentation [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1eyyzaux0ze5ln1k03gl338avbj.htm).  The basic structure is, write a fcmp function that takes a character value as input (for a character format) and returns a character value, and then call that fcmp function *with no arguments* in the format; the input value for the format will be provided automatically.

In 9.3+:

```
data have;
length cardno $32;
input cardno;
datalines;
1234567890123456
0000153456789152
0000000000000000
1111111111111111
9999999999999999
0123456
01234567897456
0123154654564897987445
;;;;
run;

proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.fmts;
  function check16fmt(charval $) $;
    length retval $16;
    if length(charval) = 16 then retval='VALID VALUE';
    else retval='_ERROR_';
    return(retval);
  endsub;
run;

options cmplib=work.funcs;

proc format;
  value $chk16f
  low-high = [check16fmt()];
quit;

data want;
  set have;
  format cardno $chk16f.;
run;
```